# LINQ - Find item index in listbox

Tags: c#, linq, listbox

I using this code to get item index in listbox:

```
string searchfor = "B";
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    listBox1.SelectedIndex = i;
    if (searchfor == listBox1.Text)
        Console.WriteLine(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
}
```

List items:

```
A
B  => 1
F
E
R
B  => 5
Y
B  => 7
G
B  => 8
```

Can anyone help me to do it with linq?

Comment: ListBox and Console in one method? Interesting

Answer (score 4):

You can use the overload of [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that includes the item's index:

```
listBox1.Items
        .Select((item, index) => new {item, index})
        .Where(ix => ix.item == searchFor)
        .Select(ix => ix.index);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string searchfor = "B";
var Items = listbox1.Items.Where( item => item.Text == searchfor);
//in case there are more than 1
Items.ForEach( i => Console.WriteLine(i.SelectedIndex))
```

or

```
string searchfor = "B";
var Item = listbox1.Items.FirstOrDefault( item => item.Text == searchfor);
Console.WriteLine(Item.SelectedIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work as well:

```
listBox1.Items.Where(item=> item.Text == searchfor)
        .ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(listBox1.Items.IndexOf(i)));
```